# Не могу поставить картинку на фон

Tags: svg, html, img

Не могу поставить картинку на фон, стоит не ровно, не так давно начал учиться веб-программированию. Вот код:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row"> 
                <div class="logo">
                    <h1>Ваш сервер</h1>
                </div>
                <a href="start.html">
                <div class="basicBox">
                    Начать играть
                    <svg width="250" height="65" viewBox="0 0 250 65">
                            <rect x='0' y='0' fill='none' width='250' height='65'/>
                    </svg>
                 </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не верстальщик, но получилось как-то так

```html
<div class="container" style="position: absolute;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row"> 
                <div class="logo">
                    <h1>Ваш сервер</h1>
                </div>
                <a href="start.html">
                <div class="basicBox">
                    Начать играть
                    <svg width="250" height="65" viewBox="0 0 250 65">
                            <rect x='0' y='0' fill='none' width='250' height='65'/>
                    </svg>
                 </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<svg xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" id="svg6783" viewBox="0 0 676.63 207.36" version="1.1">
  <defs id="defs6785">
    <filter id="filter3922" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feGaussianBlur id="feGaussianBlur3924" stdDeviation="1.7928571"/>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient6642" y2="68.076" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x2="170" y1="119.51" x1="170">
      <stop id="stop3867-7" stop-color="#a80" offset="0"/>
      <stop id="stop3869-45" stop-color="#a80" stop-opacity="0" offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient7483" y2="135.22" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x2="171.43" gradientTransform="translate(-.71429 -2)" y1="48.076" x1="172.86">
      <stop id="stop3882" stop-color="#fff" offset="0"/>
      <stop id="stop3884" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0" offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="layer1" transform="translate(66.218 -171.87)">
    <g id="g6636" transform="matrix(2.3215 0 0 2.3215 -142.46 40.397)">
      <rect id="rect3912" transform="matrix(1.0099 0 0 1.0246 -1.7678 -2.8557)" ry="24.286" filter="url(#filter3922)" width="280" y="62.362" x="38.571" height="78.571"/>
      <rect id="rect3069" opacity=".78319" ry="24.286" height="78.571" width="280" y="60.934" x="37.143" fill="#ff0"/>
      <rect id="rect3071" ry="24.286" height="78.571" width="280" y="62.362" x="38.571" fill="url(#linearGradient6642)"/>
      <path id="rect3873" fill="url(#linearGradient7483)" d="m292.66 63.031c-78.557 0.78576-157.15-0.55611-235.69 0.75-9.491 2.2961-16.641 11.611-16.375 21.438 47.906 25.338 103.4 29.225 156.66 29.219 39.545-0.4729 79.41-5.6127 116.84-18.688 5.1861-13.627-3.6254-31.419-18.75-32.688-0.89475-0.04642-1.7922-0.10605-2.6875-0.03125z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <metadata>
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work>
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
        <cc:license rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain/"/>
        <dc:publisher>
          <cc:Agent rdf:about="http://openclipart.org/">
            <dc:title>Openclipart</dc:title>
          </cc:Agent>
        </dc:publisher>
        <dc:title>Gold Button 009</dc:title>
        <dc:date>2010-10-10T23:55:41</dc:date>
        <dc:description>Golden Buttons and Banners.</dc:description>
        <dc:source>http://openclipart.org/detail/89443/gold-button-009-by-inky2010</dc:source>
        <dc:creator>
          <cc:Agent>
            <dc:title>inky2010</dc:title>
          </cc:Agent>
        </dc:creator>
        <dc:subject>
          <rdf:Bag>
            <rdf:li>3D</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>banner</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>bend</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>button</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>clip art</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>clipart</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>gold</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>golden</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>header</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>heading</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>icon</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>inkscape</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>inky2010</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>internet</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>shadow</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>vector</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>web</rdf:li>
            <rdf:li>web page</rdf:li>
          </rdf:Bag>
        </dc:subject>
      </cc:Work>
      <cc:License rdf:about="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain/">
        <cc:permits rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#Reproduction"/>
        <cc:permits rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#Distribution"/>
        <cc:permits rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#DerivativeWorks"/>
      </cc:License>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Некоторые способы установки изображения SVG на фон

#1. С помощью CSS свойств background (добавляется URL файла )
#2. С помощью `<object>` (добавляется URL )

Для сравнения оба способа в одном примере, также есть прокрутка

```css
.BackgroundImage {
        background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Test.svg') no-repeat scroll left top;
        width: 400px;
        height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SVG Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ObjectTag">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Test.svg" width="400" height="600">
          Your browser does not support SVG.
        </object>
    </div>
    <div class="BackgroundImage"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42125700/7394871)

#3. Добавление svg в формате base64

```css
#mainSVG {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
}
```

```html
<div id="mainSVG"></div>
```

#4. Интерактивность background при наведении

Это можно достичь дублированием кода SVG в CSS background и применением фильтров CSS при наведении

```css
body {
  background-color: #181818;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#twitter {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg style='fill: %23777' enable-background='new 0 0 612 612' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 612 612' xml:space='preserve' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m612 116.26c-22.525 9.981-46.694 16.75-72.088 19.772 25.929-15.527 45.777-40.155 55.184-69.411-24.322 14.379-51.169 24.82-79.775 30.48-22.907-24.437-55.49-39.658-91.63-39.658-69.334 0-125.55 56.217-125.55 125.51 0 9.828 1.109 19.427 3.251 28.606-104.33-5.24-196.84-55.223-258.75-131.17-10.823 18.51-16.98 40.078-16.98 63.101 0 43.559 22.181 81.993 55.835 104.48-20.575-0.688-39.926-6.348-56.867-15.756v1.568c0 60.806 43.291 111.55 100.69 123.1-10.517 2.83-21.607 4.398-33.08 4.398-8.107 0-15.947-0.803-23.634-2.333 15.985 49.907 62.336 86.199 117.25 87.194-42.947 33.654-97.099 53.655-155.92 53.655-10.134 0-20.116-0.612-29.944-1.721 55.567 35.681 121.54 56.485 192.44 56.485 230.95 0 357.19-191.29 357.19-357.19l-0.421-16.253c24.666-17.593 46.005-39.697 62.794-64.861z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

#twitter:hover {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg style='fill: %2300aced' enable-background='new 0 0 612 612' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 612 612' xml:space='preserve' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m612 116.26c-22.525 9.981-46.694 16.75-72.088 19.772 25.929-15.527 45.777-40.155 55.184-69.411-24.322 14.379-51.169 24.82-79.775 30.48-22.907-24.437-55.49-39.658-91.63-39.658-69.334 0-125.55 56.217-125.55 125.51 0 9.828 1.109 19.427 3.251 28.606-104.33-5.24-196.84-55.223-258.75-131.17-10.823 18.51-16.98 40.078-16.98 63.101 0 43.559 22.181 81.993 55.835 104.48-20.575-0.688-39.926-6.348-56.867-15.756v1.568c0 60.806 43.291 111.55 100.69 123.1-10.517 2.83-21.607 4.398-33.08 4.398-8.107 0-15.947-0.803-23.634-2.333 15.985 49.907 62.336 86.199 117.25 87.194-42.947 33.654-97.099 53.655-155.92 53.655-10.134 0-20.116-0.612-29.944-1.721 55.567 35.681 121.54 56.485 192.44 56.485 230.95 0 357.19-191.29 357.19-357.19l-0.421-16.253c24.666-17.593 46.005-39.697 62.794-64.861z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<a id="twitter" href="#"></a>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50430317/7394871)

#5. Анимация волн SVG в background

Весь фокус в том, что четыре закодированные (encoder) волны SVG размещены в background и их анимация реализуется в CSS c помощью смещения фона

```
@keyframes move-forever1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-75%, 0%);
  }
}
```

```css
body
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#03396c;
}

.divider {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  float:left;
}

.wave {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 400%;
  height: 50px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
}

.parallax1 {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg class='editorial' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 24 176 28' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpath id='gentle-wave' d='M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z' /%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg class='parallax1'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23gentle-wave' x='50' y='3' fill='%23f461c1'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 25% 100%;
  animation: move-forever1 15s linear infinite;
}
.parallax2 {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg class='editorial' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 24 176 28 ' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpath id='gentle-wave' d='M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z' /%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg class='parallax2'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23gentle-wave' x='50' y='0' fill='%234579e2'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 25% 100%;
  animation: move-forever2 18s linear infinite;
}
.parallax3 {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg class='editorial' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 24 176 28 ' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpath id='gentle-wave' d='M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z' /%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg class='parallax2'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23gentle-wave' x='50' y='0' fill='%233461c1'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 25% 100%;
  animation: move-forever3 15s linear infinite;
}
.parallax4 {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg class='editorial' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 24 176 28 ' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpath id='gentle-wave' d='M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z' /%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg class='parallax2'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23gentle-wave' x='50' y='0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 25% 100%;
  bottom: -10px;
  animation: move-forever4 8s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move-forever1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-75%, 0%);
  }
}
@keyframes move-forever2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-75%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}
@keyframes move-forever3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-25%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-75%, 0%);
  }
}
@keyframes move-forever4 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
  <div class="wave parallax1"></div>
  <div class="wave parallax2"></div>
  <div class="wave parallax3"></div>
  <div class="wave parallax4"></div>
</div>
```

[Источник](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1060870/28748)

Answer (score 0):

Если не так давно начал, то я советую выбросить к чертям бутстрап и прочие помогалки. Это до добра не доведёт. Что по вопросу, то в `svg` у прямоугольника свойство `fill='none'` надо изменить на `fill='red'`, например. Это цвет заливки.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!)

Answer (score 0):

Если фото то:

```
      body {
        background: url("url фото");
      }
```

Вот и все.