# Не работает SVG, встроенный в CSS, с помощью background-image

Tags: css, html5, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Я пытаюсь сделать это с встроенным SVG внутри CSS, но это не работает.

Вот оригинал встроенного инлайн SVG:

---

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cmdw/pen/vQqzyB)

Вот SVG встроенный в CSS с помощью `background-image`:

---

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/honk007/pen/wvBgxGZ)

---

```
.divider{
        content                   : " ";
        height                    : 25px;
        width                     : 100%;
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg class='editorial' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 24 150 28'><defs><path id='gentle-wave' d='M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z' /></defs><g class='parallax1'><use xlink:href='#gentle-wave' x='50' y='3' fill='#f461c1' /></g></svg>");

        background-size        : 49px 100%;
        -webkit-background-size: 49px 100%;
        position               : absolute;
        top                    : -25px;
    }
```

Я думаю, что кавычки являются причиной проблемы.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Inline SVG in CSS doing background image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59398259/7394871) от участника  [@Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260308/mike).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59398259/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Встраивание SVG может быть не лучшим вариантом, в основном из-за анимации. Ниже один из способов сделать это.

Символ `#` зарезервирован в URL для обозначения начала идентификатора фрагмента. Он должен быть записан как - `%23`.

Для достижения анимации нам нужно продублировать `<path>` в каждом из встроенных SVG. Также, нужно было внести некоторые изменения в область `viewport` SVG, чтобы повторить выравнивание.

```css
body
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#03396c;
}

.divider {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  float:left;
}

.wave {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 400%;
  height: 50px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
}

.parallax1 {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg class='editorial' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 24 176 28' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpath id='gentle-wave' d='M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z' /%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg class='parallax1'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23gentle-wave' x='50' y='3' fill='%23f461c1'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 25% 100%;
  animation: move-forever1 15s linear infinite;
}
.parallax2 {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg class='editorial' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 24 176 28 ' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpath id='gentle-wave' d='M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z' /%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg class='parallax2'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23gentle-wave' x='50' y='0' fill='%234579e2'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 25% 100%;
  animation: move-forever2 18s linear infinite;
}
.parallax3 {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg class='editorial' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 24 176 28 ' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpath id='gentle-wave' d='M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z' /%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg class='parallax2'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23gentle-wave' x='50' y='0' fill='%233461c1'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 25% 100%;
  animation: move-forever3 15s linear infinite;
}
.parallax4 {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg class='editorial' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 24 176 28 ' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpath id='gentle-wave' d='M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z' /%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg class='parallax2'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23gentle-wave' x='50' y='0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 25% 100%;
  bottom: -10px;
  animation: move-forever4 8s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move-forever1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-75%, 0%);
  }
}
@keyframes move-forever2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-75%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}
@keyframes move-forever3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-25%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-75%, 0%);
  }
}
@keyframes move-forever4 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
  <div class="wave parallax1"></div>
  <div class="wave parallax2"></div>
  <div class="wave parallax3"></div>
  <div class="wave parallax4"></div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Inline SVG in CSS doing background image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399812/7394871) от участника  [@Brett DeWoody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438581/brett-dewoody).</sub>

Comment: а scroll должен быть ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Привет! Это footer, а не вся страница. Тут ставились другие задачи, - сделать parallax нескольких волн в footer

Comment: Саша я не про подвал - а про то что прокрутка есть - много

Comment: @MaximLensky Ну это же переводной топик EnSO, стараюсь переводить один в один авторские ответы, чтобы не было лишних заморочек с лицензией.Но ведь всегда есть возможность дать дополнительный ответ на свой вкус